# Alias not working as intended in .bashrc, while command does

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

If I execute the following through the shell, it works as intended, i.e. it finds the last modified file and outputs it using `cat`:

```
aux="$(find  /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" ")"; cat "${aux}"
```

Whereas, if I try to assign it to an alias in .bashrc, it does not work (I am uncertain about what it does, it seems as if the `cat` command is being used, as I am prompted to input text). This is the alias, an exact copypaste between "":

```
 alias readlast="aux="$(find  /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" ")"; cat "${aux}""
```

Note that it does work when assigned directly through the shell, but I want it to be a permanent alias.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: alises are not for complex commands and are somewhat depreciated. Use a function instead. function aux { foo}

Comment: Perhaps: `function readlast() { aux=$(find  /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" ")
             cat "${aux}" 
        
}`

Comment: Note that if you use a function, you can do things like specifying a path as argument with `find "$1" -type f ...`

Answer (score 2):

The question's syntax highlighting should show you where you went wrong: the alias starts with a double quote, and then you use another double quote, closing the original, so the command substitution (and "${aux}" later on) is evaluated when the alias is created, not when it is run. So if you run `alias readlast`, it would look like:

```
alias readlast="aux=<name-of-file>; cat "
```

The `"${aux}"` is of course empty, because it wasn't set at the time the alias was created. That's why `cat` is waiting for input - without a filename, it just echoes back standard input.

You could fix it by using single quotes for the entire alias definition (and removing the single quotes from within the alias):

```
alias readlast='aux="$(find /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" ")"; cat "${aux}"'
```

Or use a function:

```
readlast()
{
    aux="$(find /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
      sort -n |
      tail -1 |
      cut -f2- -d" ")"
    cat "${aux}"
}
```

As a side note, you can simplify the pipe using `sed`:

```
readlast()
{
    aux="$(find /home/w/Dropbox/notes/ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
      sort -zrn |
      sed -z 's/[0-9.]* //; q')"
    cat "${aux}"
}
```

The `\0` in `-printf` and `-z` for `sort`/`sed` is input delimited with the ASCII NUL character instead of newlines. It's the only character not valid in a path, so it's the safest for dealing with filenames and paths. With `-r`, `sort` will reverse the order for you, and the `sed` command then strips off the timestamp and quits after the first line of input.